# How to find the all the nested dependent objects in oracle while calling a procedure from different schema

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 schemas - A & B. I have a procedure in a package in schema A, which I want to refer to from schema B. I had given the grant on this package in A schema and created a synonym for that in schema B. But the procedure calls a series of procedures inside one other. So When I am running the procedure it gives table/view doesn't exist. I tried to find out the dependent objects and give grant and create synonyms for few of them. But it seems the list of dependent objects is too long. So, i was just wondering if there is any way, I can find out all the objects for whom I need to grant and create synonym at one go, rather then running and checking one by one..

Thanks for your help.

Abha.

Comment: How did you find the dependent objects, and how/why is it 'too long'? Are you using, or looking for, a recursive query against `all_dependencies`? This isn't generally an issue, by default; so is the package using [invoker's rights](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-41D23DE7-3C07-41CF-962B-F92B696594B5), and if so does it need to?

Comment: I just went in to the package that was called inside the procedure one by one and gave the grant. But for few packages I did the same thing, but it seems each package is calling a new package so it is kind of difficult to go and check one by one inside the calls. And , no the package is not usng AUTHID.  It is not an issue, I just want to get a methd by which I can get all the objects that are being called internally when I call a certain package.procedure.

Comment: If your packages have the default definers rights then you don't need to grant anything else. That's one of the advantages of using packages - everything they use and call, including other packages, is hidden from the caller. If you are getting that error then invoker's rights must be kicking in somewhere. Anyway, you might also want to look at [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/plscope.html) to see more about what is being used.

Comment: Hi, sorry, the package (in schema A) that is called from my package (schema B) do have invokers right. It has been defined as :
        'create or replace package WF_LOCAL_SYNCH AUTHID CURRENT_USER ' in APPS schema. I will look into the link that you have provided to dig in more.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of some different topologies that can cause this problem - and I will start with the easiest explanation I can come up with first.

If you have your tables and your code (packages) on schema A.

Given the following test objects

```
create table tst_table(tst_val int); 

create or replace package tst_pkg as 
  procedure tst_insert; 
end tst_pkg; 
/

create or replace package body tst_pkg  as 
  procedure tst_insert as
  begin
    insert into tst_table (tst_val) values (44); 
  end; 
end tst_pkg; 
/
```

You can grant execute on tst_pkg to the other user aka schema B and this other user will be able to use the tst_insert procedure - as follows

```
SQL> exec iasim.tst_pkg.tst_insert;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But - if you have this topology and you should happen to define your package using "authid current_user" - then the granted execute is not sufficient anymore.

If you change your package definition to

```
create or replace package tst_pkg authid current_user as 
  procedure tst_insert; 
end tst_pkg; 
/
```

You will get this error when you try to execute the procedure

```
SQL> exec iasim.tst_pkg.tst_insert;
BEGIN iasim.tst_pkg.tst_insert; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "IASIM.TST_PKG", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

So - if this is the case you should just compile your package without "authid current_user" and grant the user the execute privilege - which is the privs needed to insert rows into tst_table i my example if its done via the procedure in test_pkg.

Please let me know if this helps or if you have arranged the pieces different.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your comments.. I am using the packages without authid clause, so your 1st scenario holds good to me. 
But my problem is that the package (tst_pkg in your example) to which i have given the grant also have a call to other package (B) and package B calls another package (C) and so on. So I need to give the grant to all the packages that have been called internally by my calling package's procedure.

Comment: create package body tst_pkg  as 
  procedure tst_insert as
  begin
  PKG_B.proc_b();  
  end tst_pkg;

  create package body PKG_B  as 
   procedure proc_b as
  begin
   PKG_C.proc_c();
  end;
  
  create package body PKG_C  as 
    procedure proc_c as
  begin
   PKG_D.proc_C();
  end; 
  

So when I give grant to package tst_pkg, it is not enough. I also need to give grant to other dependent packages i.e PKG_B,PKG_c and so on. But how to figure out all the dependent packages, so that I can give grant to all of them?

Comment: @Abha - its quite easy to find the dependencies in the ALL_DEPENDENCIES view - you could run a query like select * from ALL_DEPENDENCIES where name = '<name of your object>;

Comment: This query just give only one level down dependencies, not the nested objects.